# How can i associate folders to options in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I made an autocomplete searchbar, but when i click on any option they dont do nothing, i wanted to used them like buttons (href) and i really dont know how can i do it..

i want to associate the "availableKeywords" to folders from 1 to 16
the search bar is autocompleting right but my problem is i wanted to make it when i click it redirecting to the folders ive said before

this is the code

```js
let availableKeywords = [
    'Afonso Nabeto',
    'Bianca Silva',
    'Duarte Rocha',
    'Guilherme Costa',
    'Hugo Silva',
    'Joana Rita',
    'João Teixeira',
    'João Ladeira',
    'Keila Mendes',
    'Leonardo Melendre',
    'Lucas Diniz',
    'Marlon Silva',
    'Miguel Lourenço',
    'Ruben Magalhães',
    'Tomé Almeida',
    'Ygor Mendonça',
];

const resultBox = document.querySelector(".result-box");
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");

inputBox.onkeyup = function (){
    let result = [];
    let input = inputBox.value;
    if (input.length) {
        result = availableKeywords.filter((keyword)=> {
            return keyword.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase());
        });
        console.log(result);
    }
    display(result);

    if (!result.length) {
        resultBox.innerHTML = '';
    }
}

function display(result){
    const content = result.map((list)=> {
        return "<li onclick=selectInput(this)>" + list + "</li>";
    });

    resultBox.innerHTML = "<ul>" + content.join('') + "</ul>";
}

function selectInput(list){
    resultBox.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
.search-box {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid var(--primary);
    background: var(--background);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}  

input {
    flex: 1;
    height: 35px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: var(--primary);
}

button {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

button .fa-solid {
    width: 22px;
    color: var(--primary);
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

::placeholder {
    color: var(--primary);
}

.result-box ul {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    max-height: 75px;
}

.result-box li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--primary);
}

.result-box ul li:hover {
    background: var(--static);
}

.result-box {
    max-height: 75px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Pesquisar" autocomplete="off">
    <button><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="result-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps create a working snippet with the minimal amount of HTML that reproduces ths.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss done ig:)

Comment: You currently have the clicks tied to a function but also mention that you want to use href. Are you trying to run a function or link to another page?

Comment: @abney317 yes, what i want to do is like, when i click on the option opens another page, another link, thats actually another folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just linking to another page within your list, you can directly add an anchor tag around your list items.

```
return `<li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com?name=${list}">${list}</a></li>`;
```

```js
let availableKeywords = [
    'Afonso Nabeto',
    'Bianca Silva',
    'Duarte Rocha',
    'Guilherme Costa',
    'Hugo Silva',
    'Joana Rita',
    'João Teixeira',
    'João Ladeira',
    'Keila Mendes',
    'Leonardo Melendre',
    'Lucas Diniz',
    'Marlon Silva',
    'Miguel Lourenço',
    'Ruben Magalhães',
    'Tomé Almeida',
    'Ygor Mendonça',
];

const resultBox = document.querySelector(".result-box");
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");

inputBox.onkeyup = function (){
    let result = [];
    let input = inputBox.value;
    if (input.length) {
        result = availableKeywords.filter((keyword)=> {
            return keyword.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase());
        });
        console.log(result);
    }
    display(result);

    if (!result.length) {
        resultBox.innerHTML = '';
    }
}

function display(result){
    const content = result.map((list)=> {
        return `<li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com?name=${list}">${list}</a></li>`;
    });

    resultBox.innerHTML = "<ul>" + content.join('') + "</ul>";
}

function selectInput(list){
    resultBox.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
.search-box {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid var(--primary);
    background: var(--background);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}  

input {
    flex: 1;
    height: 35px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: var(--primary);
}

button {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

button .fa-solid {
    width: 22px;
    color: var(--primary);
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

::placeholder {
    color: var(--primary);
}

.result-box ul {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    max-height: 75px;
}

.result-box li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--primary);
}

.result-box ul li:hover {
    background: var(--static);
}

.result-box {
    max-height: 75px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Pesquisar" autocomplete="off">
    <button><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="result-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked, tysm